# is there any possibility of connecting ACCELEROMETER + ARDUINO UNO + GSM module together?

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, accelerometer

I am lakshman a mechanical engineer,i have a question that is there any possibility of connecting ACCELEROMETER + ARDUINO UNO + GSM module together???

so that i can take the output value from Accelerometer so that to make a call to a preprogrammed number???

Plz help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide links to the devices you have in mind, or is this just a very general question?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is perfectly possible.  Typically:

- Accelerometer is either an analog, SPI or I2C interface.
- GSM is usually a UART interface
- The Arduino UNO has all four interfaces (analog, SPI, I2C and UART) available on separate pins.

The rest is just a SMOP.

Comment: A little too much jargon, @Majenko. I had to Google what SMOP meant. ;) (And some of the results probably were not what **you** meant).

Comment: @NickGammon Just a "Small Matter of Programming" - i.e., if you have to ask this then you have a lot of learning to do before you can write the software, and while it would be simple for us, for someone that doesn't even know if you can connect these things together it's not going to be a simple task